# Multi-meters/voltmeters batteries and resistance measurements

Tags: multimeter

In a popular text it is written:

"Multi-meters also have one or more batteries in them to power the resistance measurement. By supplying a small current and measuring the voltage drop, they measure resistance,"

Considering measurements; is the battery only needed for resistance measurements but not for current or voltage measurements?

And is the battery voltage regulated inside the multi-meter before used as a reference voltage?

Comment: wtf? "popular text"? what the hell are you talking about? That text is clearly from the 60s talking about analogue meters! jeez!

Comment: As PlasmaHH says: this only concerns old fashioned analogue meters ! My old analogue meter (from the 1980s) does not have an internal reference, the battery voltage is the "reference" and you have to "zero" the meter, short the leads and set a knob so the meter reads "0" (zero) which is at the right end of the scale ! More accurate meters probably do have a proper internal reference voltage although I've never seen that myself.

Comment: this was from Paul Horowitz's popular book latest version; but probably this info is outdated if you say so

Comment: Old analog multi-meters have a moving coil meter that does not need power to measure voltage or current, but need the battery to measure resistance. Modern DVM's need a battery to power the electronics which converts the analog voltage or current to a digital signal, and to power the LCD display.

Answer (score 1):

One thing Im sure of a digital meter needs a battery to test Continuity. It puts a small current through the section being tested and may fail to produce a result if the resistance is too high for the supplied current.

http://www.ladyada.net/library/metertut/continuity.html